# Obfuscate string with on SAMD21

Tags: arduino-ide, c++

I'am looking for a way to obfuscate string at compile time on my personal board build with an SAMD21, i'am using Arduino IDE to compile and upload code. All solution I've found [like this one](https://github.com/adamyaxley/Obfuscate) for example doesn't work with Arduino IDE beceause it's for c++14 (using `constexpr` doesn't compile) is there a solution working for Arduino?

Comment: Arduino can use even c++17 https://forum.arduino.cc/t/c-14/633553